# Boost add_console_log yields invalid operands to binary expression error

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-log

I have the following simple setup:

```
#include <boost/log/sources/record_ostream.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/console.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/severity_logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions/keyword.hpp>


namespace mynamespace
{
    namespace keywords = boost::log::keywords;
    namespace expr = boost::log::expressions;

    enum SeverityLevel
    {
        Trace,
        Debug,
        Info,
        Warning,
        Error,
        Critical
    };


    class LoggingConfig
    {
    public:
        void init()
        {
            // Add default console logging sink
            auto format = expr::stream << expr::message;
            boost::log::add_console_log(std::cout, keywords::format=format);
        };
    };
}
```

Compiling gives this:

```
/Users/iulian/ClionProjects/project/util/logging.hpp:33:40: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('const stream_type' (aka 'const actor<base_type>') and 'const message_type' (aka 'const attribute_keyword<tag::message>'))
            auto format = expr::stream << expr::message;
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I have seen numerous example of configuring the format etc in a similar manner to what I am trying above. Why doesn't this compile?

Answer (score 0):

This is very silly - I was missing the correct includes.. specifically:

```
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/record_ostream.hpp>
```